# Subset a dataframe based on a list of words

Tags: regex, r

For example

```
List 1: 

Hello  
Green   

Data frame 2: 

Date          Sentence
1/1/2011      Hello world  
1/2/2011      Red ball and blue river  
1/3/2011      My laptop
```

The new data frame should be

```
Date      Sentence
1/1/2011  Hello world
```

Comment: If `list1` is a vector, try `data2[grepl(paste(list1, collapse = "|"), data2$Sentence),]`

Answer (score 1):

As @RichardScriven commented, you are looking for the following perhaps. By collapsing your list of keywords by the alternation operator `|`, you are essentially creating a regular expression pattern telling the regular expression engine to match either everything to the left of the alternation operator, or everything to the right of it ...

```
> x <- c('Hello', 'Green')
> df <- data.frame(DATE = c('1/1/2011', '1/2/2011', '1/3/2011'),
                 Sentence = c('Hello world', 'Red ball and blue river', 'My laptop'))
> df[grepl(paste(x, collapse = '|'), df$Sentence, ignore.case=T),]
```

Outputs

```
      DATE    Sentence
1 1/1/2011 Hello world
```